# Tables could not be fetched on MySQL Workbench at macOs (Xampp)

Tags: mysql, xampp, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

I can connect mysql server by the help of xampp app 7.3.16-0 and ı can control my database from internet browser(localhost) but there is a problem on MySQL Workbench app(8.0.17).It see my database which ı created before on ınternet browser but ı cannot see my tables because of the tables could not be fetched.I have error which is Error code : 1558 column count of mysql.proc is wrong.I use macOs and ı need help.

Thanks...